# Assign and calculate by exponential notation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, floating-point, scientific-notation

Have you ever observed this phenomenon:

If I try to calculate the following calculation in ImmediateWindow of Visual Studio 2010 C# .Net, I get this weird solution.

```
1E-9 * 100 = 0.00000010000000000000001
1E-9 * 1E+2 = 0.00000010000000000000001
```

Even if I do the calculation this way:

```
double val = 1E-9;
0.000000001
val = val * 100;
0.00000010000000000000001
```

If I calculate the same calculation in Windows calc I get the expected result:

```
1E-9 * 100 = 0,0000001
```

If someone knows something about this behaviour I would be very pleased to get the info.

Comment: Maybe the windows calculator just doesn't use doubles? Why do you assume they should have the same precision?

Comment: Are you interested in the behavior of `0.00000010000000000000001`, which is the result of trying to store decimal digits in binary computers (and has been answered many times before), or the fact that Windows Calc gets it right when the others get it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you use exponential notation or not, you're just running into floating-point accuracy.  If you want better accuracy, use decimal  e.g.:

```
decimal val = 1E-9;
0.000000001
val = val * 100;
0.0000001
```

See [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)